# How do I properly escape double quotes in a PostgreSQL like query?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a PostgreSQL table with YAML data stored in a text field.

I'm attempting to find all instances of where a key has been changed from false to true.

```
audited_changes: {"hide_on_map"=>[false, true]}
```

I can easily find all instances of this key with a like query on the attribute hide_on_map

```
    [3] pry(main)> like_query = ActiveRecord::Base.send(:sanitize_sql_like, 'hide_on_map')
Audited::Audit.where(auditable_type: 'Lot').where('audited_changes like ?', "%#{like_query}%").count

   (245.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "audits" WHERE "audits"."auditable_type" = $1 AND (audited_changes like '%hide\_on\_map%')  [["auditable_type", "Lot"]]
=> 1710
```

However, adding double quotes breaks this

```
[4] pry(main)> like_query = ActiveRecord::Base.send(:sanitize_sql_like, '"hide_on_map"')
Audited::Audit.where(auditable_type: 'Lot').where('audited_changes like ?', "%#{like_query}%").count

   (238.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "audits" WHERE "audits"."auditable_type" = $1 AND (audited_changes like '%"hide\_on\_map"%')  [["auditable_type", "Lot"]]
=> 0
```

Let alone the full query

```
[5] pry(main)> like_query = ActiveRecord::Base.send(:sanitize_sql_like, '"hide_on_map"=>[false, true]')
Audited::Audit.where(auditable_type: 'Lot').where('audited_changes like ?', "%#{like_query}%").count

   (245.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "audits" WHERE "audits"."auditable_type" = $1 AND (audited_changes like '%"hide\_on\_map"=>[false, true]%')  [["auditable_type", "Lot"]]
=> 0
```

Started going down a rabbit hole of converting to JSONB but this adds several additional complications that I'd rather not have to solve. Suggestions on a properly formed LIKE clause?

For those asking, two examples of this query directly in SQL at the psql prompt.

```
select count(*) from audits where audited_changes like '%"hide\_on\_map"%';

select count(*) from audits where audited_changes like '%\"hide\_on\_map\"%';
```

Both resulted in 0 results.

Comment: Use prepared statements instead of SQL Injection.

Comment: Have you tried with a \ before your quote ?

Comment: @TheImpaler didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: @EmilienBaudet I have. No effect. I've tried it directly in SQL with psql and it didn't work either.

Comment: Double quotes in LIKE work just fine, they don't need escaping as they don't have any special meaning to start with.  Show us exactly what you tried in psql.  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4QfyTgjbW9RuetutTGwvrg/0

Comment: How many rows do you have in your `Audited::Audit` table?

Comment: @jjanes edited question to included SQL queries.

Comment: @max just over 103 million records but those are constrained by a record type reducing it to 63,000 and the last 90 days reducing it further to 6,000. For now, I'm just searching for `hide_on_map` and iterating through all of them. It's really more an exercise in why I can't query for certain text in a LIKE query.

Comment: Hmm, then I guess converting all the legacy data is going to be tough. Try `where( Audited::Audit.arel_table[:audited_changes].matches(like_query) )`.

Comment: @max it was my stupid misunderstanding of the data being stored. See answer below and my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that there is not a unique way to express that data in YAML:

```yaml
hide_on_map:
  - no
  - yes
```

```yaml
"hide_on_map": [false, true]
```

are both valid YAML representations of your data.

I fear you cannot avoid using some native type, or at least a "compacted" JSON text (which would contain literally `'"hide_on_map":[false,true]'`.

Comment: I think there are two choices here; create a JSON/JSONB column and convert the legacy data with a YAML parser and put it back into the DB or live with the fact the data is not going to be queryable.

Comment: @rewritten this is sort of the right answer but it was me being stupid. When viewing the data in the Rails console it was transformed to the later representation, the one I posted BUT the stored values are in the state you mentioned.

A really stupid mistake on my part not properly checking the raw audit data. Thanks for the help and sorry for the waste of time!